# How to keep writting to a file until stop method is called

Tags: c#, multithreading, io

I have a method that reads data from a device for 5 seconds and writes it to a binary file.

```
// Start acquisition
    try
    {
       // create file stream
       using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
       {
          using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
          {
              // start acquisition thread
       deviceManagerObj.StartAcquisition(deviceManagerObj.deviceConfigurations);

             // to stop the application after a specified time, get start time
             DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
             DateTime stopTime = startTime.AddSeconds(numSecondsRunning);


             // this is the data processing thread; data received from the devices will be written out to a file here
             while (DateTime.Now < stopTime)
             {
                float[] data = deviceManagerObj.ReadData(numValuesAtOnce);

                // write data to file
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                    writer.Write(data[i]);
             }
          }
        }
  }
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", ex.Message);
}
finally
{
   // stop data acquisition
   deviceManagerObj.StopAcquisition();

   Console.WriteLine("Press any key exit...");
   Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

I would like to break this method in two: start and stop. When start is called, it keeps reading the data from the device and writing it to the file. When stops is called it finishes everything.  I would like to do something like the following, but ensuring is not blocking and it stops writing when the stop is called. How can I do this properly? Do I need a separate threat?

```
public void start() {
   try
   {
        // create file stream
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
           using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
           {
               // start acquisition thread\
       deviceManagerObj.StartAcquisition(deviceManagerObj.deviceConfigurations);
               // this is the data processing thread; data received from the devices will be written out to a file here
                while (true???) // I dont know how to do this
                {
                float[] data = deviceManagerObj.ReadData(numValuesAtOnce);

                // write data to file
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                    writer.Write(data[i]);
        }
      }
   }
}

public void stop()
{
    // stop data acquisition
    deviceManagerObj.StopAcquisition();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key exit...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) to do something like this:

```
public class Worker
{
    private CancellationTokenSource m_CancellationTokenSource;

    public void Start()
    {

        m_CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var token = m_CancellationTokenSource.Token;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            //Prepare the things you need to do before the loop, like opening the files and devices

            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //Do something here like continuously reading and writing

            }

        }, token)
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            //This will run after stopping, close files and devices here
        });

    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        m_CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

}
```

And here you how you use this:

```
Worker worker = new Worker();

worker.Start();

//Do something here

//After a while
worker.Stop();
```

Please note that the Start method returns immediately because it will run the work on another thread from the thread-pool.